# In my model, what element type do I use for a SQL table column of type smalldatetime?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table `dates` with columns `fileid` of type `int` and `dtime` of time `smalldatetime`. The is meant to keep track of the date and time that a file was uploaded. What should `???` be in the following piece of my model? Should it just be a string, and if so, do I have to parse that string to use it (e.g. if I have a functionality in my server for deleting all files that are over 30 days old)?

```
[Table(Name = "dates")]
public class Date
{
   public Date()
   {

   }

   [Column]
   public int fileid { get; set; }
   [Column]
   public ??? dtime { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use DateTime.

Source: [MSDN official data type mappings list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That is a useful piece of documentation